# JSON - Array Error for Multiline string output | nodejs | node-request

Tags: json, node.js, express, node-request

I ran the following code in node js

```
const request = require("request");

const GetUserInventory = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api-trade.opskins.com/ITrade/GetUserInventory/v1/',
  qs: { uid: '3192035', app_id: '1' },
  json: true
};

request(GetUserInventory, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});
```

The output I got is the following. Here the values of the strings are not displayed. That is, they are displayed as [object] How do I get the desired output as stated in the picture?

```
{
  status: 1,
  time: 1536729167,
  current_page: 1,
  total_pages: 1,
  response: {
    items: [
      [Object]
    ],
    total: '1',
    items_in_active_offers: null,
    user_data: {
      username: 'Mowrish gamdom.com',
      avatar: 'https://steamcdn-a.opskins.media/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/d7/d7cf2c088d4398bed904ae540b36211e1af202f2.jpg'
    },
    sort_parameters: [
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object],
      [Object]
    ]
  }
}
```

The output, that I expect is as follows. How to get this output?

[image: Desired output]

I have tried `JSON.parse` of `body` before console.log() instead of `json: true` value in GetUserInventory. It didn't work. And Also, I tried `JSON.stringify` of `body`. The same happened with it too

Comment: what is your desired Op ?@Mowrish

Comment: items: [
      [Object]
    ],  This array should be replaced with its values such as [Desired output](https://gyazo.com/8f3bea8d3ce41f1e6fbeeb10bf306192)

Comment: Can  you post `console.log( body)` data @Mowrish

Comment: Also, Note the key: value. When there happens to be an output the key is not wriiten within "" (double quotes) How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: [console.log](https://gyazo.com/caa05ba17d3861b44803560ac47112f2)

Comment: Can you add image data as text format because I am not able to copy exact data for testing purpose @Mowrish

Comment: const request = require("request");

const GetUserInventory = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api-trade.opskins.com/ITrade/GetUserInventory/v1/',
  qs: { uid: '3192035', app_id: '1' },
  json: true
};

request(GetUserInventory, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  console.log(body);
});

Comment: I don't know how to send in the code format in the comments section. Can I send you through mail if that's okay with you?

Comment: Just edit the post and add in text format  instead of image @Mowrish

Comment: I did that Sir. Now I guess, I gave you the code for testing. Would be glad to get this issue resolved at the earliest. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try following if you want the output same as in screenshot you posted

```
request(GetUserInventory, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  obj = JSON.stringify(body);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: I tried this. I get the output as raw data and not in JSON format. And yes, in this case I do get the desired array

Answer (score 0):

you have issue with response body. so there may be you have not set content-type when you call API.

The header just denotes what the content is encoded in. It is not necessarily possible to deduce the type of the content from the content itself, i.e. you can't necessarily just look at the content and know what to do with it. That's what HTTP headers are for, they tell the recipient what kind of content they're (supposedly) dealing with.

pass content type in header:

> Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8;

so your response will be in JSON format you can access it.

or you can try this, this will also works.

> obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body));

Comment: I tried what you said. I included the header, I get JSON with the same thing and for the second one, I am still getting the output as raw data. If I pass the value  json: true , the content type should be set default to application.json in the header and that the content type is not necessary to include and the parsing is also not required.

Comment: can you console this -  console.log(body.response.items);
sometime if value array larger then it will show as [object]

Comment: Or where you send response there may be your response data is string.
so try this - res.json(JSON.parse(body));

Comment: Still I get [object] as the array not the string's value

Comment: there is only two things happen when you send response
1) your response data is string, so you should pass response like this - res.json(JSON.parse(body));

2) or your response data is already JSON, then it should works in your code.

but still you can try this - res.json(JSON.stringify(body)) and at client side you can parse it.

Comment: also pass header like this, i was facing same things when i was used request module, it solved by using this:

 headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
'User-Agent': 'request'
    }